# Is "I will treat you so good" correct? What about "...very good'?

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say this? I mean, I personally would rather put 'very good' at the end of the sentence that has a future connotation. And I'd use 'so good' only if we are talking about past experiences ('I treated you so good').

Do you think 'so good' works perfectly with both examples?

Comment: Consider using "well", as it sounds better, and will bump you up a couple of social classes, too. :p

Answer (score 3):

Regarding "so" vs. "very": it's a matter of personal preference. They do not, in and of themselves, carry the connotations of past or future.

Also, like @ralph.m said in his comment, consider using *well* instead:

> BAD: I don't speak English **very good**.
>   GOOD: I don't speak English **very well**.
>   ◆◆◆
>   *Good* is an *adjective*: 'She is a very good singer.'
>   *Well* is an *adverb*: 'She sings very well.'

(*Longman Dictionary of Common Errors*)

Comment: *Well* is also an adjective: "I am well."

Comment: *Good* is also an adverb: "I'm feeling pretty good."

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Correct. I only quoted parts relevant to the OP's example.

Comment: In American English adjectives are commonly used instead of their adverb counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

"So" (when used in this sense) implies a comparison of sorts -- "You will like that shop *so* well that you will want to return again and again", or "The cup was *so* full that it overflowed."

Even when the comparand clause is not present, the comparison is implied -- "I will treat you *so* well" basically begs the listener to imagine the elided "that" prepositional clause.  When you merely want to imply a superior degree of "treat" you should use a different word -- "very" or "extremely", eg.

Neither approach implies anything about past/present/future (other than the overall tense of the sentence).